# data collection for statistics: from web to a database

Tags: r, database, webforms, statistics, redcap

I'm a statistician by trade and I'd like some recommendations on how to set up a website that can collect data into a database.  For personal use, I use Google Forms to collect data, and everything gets populated into a spreadsheet.  However, this may not be appropriate in a more professional setting, especially when we have multiple pages/forms.  I imagine two uses:

1. A website where I can send the link to others so they can fill out, similar to Google Forms.
2. A website where only authorized users can log in to fill out data.  Think of a setting where patients are followed periodically in a research study.  It'd be cool to have the clinician enter the data directly into the database as he/she fills out the forms as opposed to having another data analyst transcribe his written forms into the database.

The obvious solution would be to hire a web developer.  However, I like doing things myself when they are manageable.  I imagine a web developer would have to know html, php, and database knowledge (eg, MySQL or PostgreSQL).  My experience in these are limited to setting up a wordpress blog on my linux server.  My experience with html is also limited as I use emacs org-mode to generate them from plain text.  I hope to hear about solutions with a minimal learning curve.  My preference of course would be free open source software and Linux-based, but I'd like to hear all available solutions (our data manager is a Windows user).

I recently read a [post](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/redcap-tool-collecting-clinical-trails-data?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+linuxjournalcom+%28Linux+Journal+-+The+Original+Magazine+of+the+Linux+Community%29&utm_content=Google+Reader) on Linux Journal that mentions [REDCap](http://www.project-redcap.org/cite.php), but it seems you have to get institutional permission to use.

I also tagged "R" on this post as I'd like to hear what R users are doing about data collection.  I'll ultimately analyze the data with R, but all data analysis begins with the scientific question and data collection.

Thanks!

UPDATE 10/4/2010: Thanks everyone for the responses so far.  It appears most of the third-party solutions proposed so far has data housed in a database hosted by the vendor.  I'd like to house all data in our SQL Server.  That is, data entry from the web enters the database in real time, ready for data analysis.

Comment: Great question. I learned a lot from the answers.

Comment: Hi Vinh. If you can, I would definitely choose REDCap as it's very friendly with R. In fact, the summary statistics and univariate graphics are created with R. Also, I'm currently developing an R package that will target REDCap's data API.  --- Disclaimer: I'm in charge of the R related efforts for REDCap here at Vanderbilt University.

Comment: #Vinh, DASH provides you with local storage.

Comment: @Jeff Does REDCap allow subjects to enter their own data? Does REDCap allow one to setup questions with logic and piping?

Comment: Did you really look at the LimeSurvey software? It allows you to set up professional questionnaires on your **own** website. Open source and free. And good.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the [limesurvey.org](http://www.limesurvey.org) project is of interest ...

Comment: I am currently using limesurvey for a project survey with +100 questions and with +2700 respondents. No problems at all. In fact, if you are the kind of guy who installs wordpress on your own server, then I see no reason not to use limesurvey.

LS even have an R export feature: http://docs.limesurvey.org/tiki-index.php?page=Exporting+Results&structure=English+Instructions+for+LimeSurvey#R_Export

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me like you've got yourself a med study. There are a plethora of concerns that come to mind just from what you've described you want to do. Not the least of which is privacy. Where is it going to be hosted? Have you received consent from the patients to be collecting and transmitting their information electronically? What data are you storing, if any, that could combine to present their identity.

Personally, I steer clear of DIY online data collection tools. I pay a firm, like Ipsos, Research Now/E-Rewards,  to program and manage data collection using questionnaires that I have designed. The reason is, knowing how to design research and analyze data is one thing. But if you've been trained in statistics - I can safely argue that you "don't know shit" about data collection. Sure you may know a bunch about sampling theory, but when it comes to getting data in - it's best to leave it to the pros.

There are a number of "industrial quality" online data collection tools available.

- Confirmit (Pretty much the gold standard for online data collection)
- DASH (Smaller following, but incredibly flexible)

There are also purely web based solutions, some of which are free (not that I would recommend using them)

- QuestionPro
- SurveyMonkey
- Zoomerang

Although, unless you're doing a study with over 50 patients, I would just recommend getting the Physicians or their assistants to fill out Excel sheets and send them to your co.

Also, it's unlikely that you'll need to set-up a username/password system. What you want is referred to as an "open-link". Where respondents click a link and enter information, identifier info can be added by the respondent. You don't need a password because people can only INPUT information, not read it.

Most of the systems I mentioned above work on the idea of emailing a respondent (a clinician) with a link to a web based survey. Which could be easily adapted to your specific needs and act as a reminder to the clinician to fill out the form.

If your question types are simple. I'm sure you could hire a programmer to put together a website that has the forms you need behind an authorized front end. PHP/MySQL would likely do the trick. But, I would double check the privacy laws in your jurisdiction surrounding medical research before going ahead.

Comment: Thanks for your response Brandon.  You're probably right, most of us probably "don't know shit" about the technical aspects and implementation of data collection.  Like you said, we usually have others do this for us.  I'm just asking for my own self-enrichment -- computer DIY is a hobby of mine.  I also like to know what's out there to evaluate how I/we do things.  Of course, we would need consent and privacy laws will need to be abided.

Answer (score 4):

I have conducted medial research using an online form (actually two of them). My questions were quite discrete and particular to the disease I was researching.

Previously in a related project, I had created two or three page questionnaires which were printed and then subjects and surgeons filled out the forms and our research coordinator would enter them into our database. It was a lot of work with lots of room for error. I did not like it. Online forms were much better.

I used SurveyGizmo and was happy with it. I looked at lots of options about two years ago. Google Forms did not exist at that time. I went with SurveryGizmo primarily because they had a a statement (attestation) that they were compliant with HIPAA. I could not ensure security such as ssl connections with the other websites. However in order to get myself into that capability (https connections) I had to buy the enterprise level eventhough on every other capability I could have used the free service. Also SurveyGizmo offered a 50% reduction for non-profits which our research institute qualified for.

SurveryGizmo was easy to design and put into production without having to program myself. It was easy to download the data in csv format and read that straight into R. Although I had some weird issues that I needed help with. I had to use the "old" format for export so that it came as a straigtforward csv. Furthermore, the csv file had the odd feature of the the first TWO rows being header rows. But I [solved that problem with the help of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293131/reading-first-row-as-header-is-easy-what-gives-with-two-rows-being-the-header).

SurveryGizmo has fantastic logic and piping that enbabled me to only ask relevant questions and thereby not waste the time of my respondents and even more importantly, there were no irrelevant questions to confuse respondents.

Finally, I was able to use SurveyGizmo in such a way that I could also track our (research staff) fulfillment and logistics. For instance we got notification when there were new potential subjects who were interested in participating. We were able to note FedEx tracking numbers along with the records of the corresponding subjects.

Basically it worked well.

Comment: +1 SurveyGizmo looks like a really good and inexpensive tool. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

The safest platform for collecting confidential survey data is Confirmit. There is a learning curve involved here- you will be coding in VisualSQL, which is only used in Confirmit. The survey responses will export to csv files, where you can analyze your results in R.

If you are collecting any confidential data, or data where respondents need unique access links so they can only see their own version of the survey, you will want to use Confirmit. The data is housed in Confirmit's data center, but their data is much more secure than other vendors (i.e., a third party will not be able to hack into your survey and see an individual's responses, or intercept the data that is being sent from your respondent to Confirmit).