# Need to keep two header rows in .csv file and load into R

Tags: r, csv

I have a .csv file with gene counts and sample names. I would like to be able to keep the two header rows. For example, I'd like to load a file in the format below:

```
       Sample
Gene    1        2
gene1   272.43    911.83
gene2   212.29    151.55
gene3   39.41      22.17
```

The ultimate goal is to plot sums of all gene counts by sample. Any ideas how to do this in R?

Thank you,
tmd

Comment: You don't really have two header rows. The header is "Gene", 1, 2. You can rename it as "Gene", "Sample 1", "Sample 2"

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293131/reading-in-files-with-two-header-rows) help?

Comment: I simplified because it's a really large file with many, many samples that have long names. Is it possible to keep the two header rows so that I can easily plot? Or am I just thinking about this incorrectly?

Comment: It is not possible to do this out of the box.

Comment: @ben_aaron, that just mashed the two headers together. Does anyone have suggestions on how to plot gene count matrices in R?