# Creating column label from row values

Tags: r, label

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Responseid <- c("Responseid",1,2,3,4)
q1 <- c("what is your gender",1,1,1,1)
q2 <- c("what is your age",18,28,15,40)
df <- data.frame(Responseid,q1,q2)
```

[image]

I'm wondering how to put all the row 1 values as a label for the column header, so something like this:
[image]

I have a dataset with a lot of variables and I want to put all the row 1 values as label for all the column header.

I would appreciate all the help there is! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you likely have a better solution upstream. When you import this data, you may consider setting an argument like `header = TRUE` to the function you call reading in the data, such as `read.csv(header = TRUE)` or with `readr::read_csv(col_names = TRUE)`

Comment: I tried header=TRUE but it did not work

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797840/reading-two-line-headers-in-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading two-line headers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797840/reading-two-line-headers-in-r)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293131/reading-in-files-with-two-rows-for-header

Comment: Also, if you're importing this data from Qualtrics or Survey Monkey or something like that there are dedicated packages that know how to read the data properly.